# PrintForm control visual studio - set print range?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, printing

I'm wondering if anyone knows how to set dimensions to print a certain area of a windows form in vb.net? Currently, the default is to print everything that can fit from top left corner. I would like to set the printing area to the middle of the screen. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Something like [this](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/25078214/visual-Basic-PowerPacks-PrintForm-margins.html) question?

Comment: no I am not looking to set margins, I am looking to basically snapshot the middle of the form and print only the snapshot area... im just not sure how I would set that if I can, I have spent a lot of time looking and I have not found anything